# Is there any way to pass Output of one workflow to another without using outarguments?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I have recently started working with Workflows.I am able to pass output of one activity as input to another through making use of `OutArgument` .Is it possible without using `OutArgument`.

If Possible please suggest me how?

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a workflow extension to act as a repository of variables in the scope of the whole workflow.

Create a workflow extension that contains properties.
Add the extension to the workflow application.
Set or Get the value of the properties from within Activities.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff460215(v=vs.110).aspx

In response to your comment below.

You are wrong in your assumption.  The extension "holds" the output from activity 1 which is then available to activity 2.

For example:

Create a class to hold properties:

```
public class PropertyStoreExtension
{
    int _myProperty
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return this._myProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            this._myProperty = value;
        }
   } 
}
```

Add this as an extension to your workflow:

```
PropertyStoreExtension propertyStoreExtension = new PropertyStoreExtension
WorkflowInvoker myWorkflowInstence = new        
WorkflowInvoker(myWorkflowDefinition());
myWorkflowInstence.Extensions.Add(propertyStoreExtension); 
myWorkflowInstence.Invoke()
```

Your workflow contains 2 activities:
The first takes its "output" and stores it in the extension.

```
public class Activity1_SetProperty: CodeActivity
{
   protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   {
       PropertyStoreExtension pse =context.GetExtension<PropertyStoreExtension>();

       if (pse != null)
       {
          pse.MyProperty=outputValue;                     
       }

   }
}
```

The second gets the value out of the extension.

```
public class Activity2_GetProperty: CodeActivity
{
   protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   {
       PropertyStoreExtension pse =context.GetExtension<PropertyStoreExtension>();

       if (pse != null)
       {
          int intputValue; = pse.MyProperty                     
       }

   }
}
```

Comment: But in this case is it possible to access the output of activity1 and send it to Activity2 as an input?Still I think I need to declare outArgument variable in Activity1. And then i can assign that outargument value to Extension class from Host to get it in activity2 as  an input.?Pleasae correct me if I am Wrong...